# Large array as constructor arguments fails

Tags: solidity

My goal is to pass two fairly large arrays to my constructor:

```
constructor(AggregatorV3Interface _chainlinkFeedAddress, IERC20 _currency, address[] memory _whitelistedAddresses, uint256[] memory _maxPrincipleAmounts, uint256[] memory _maxLoanDurations, uint256[] memory _interestRates) {
            
            // 0x64EaC61A2DFda2c3Fa04eED49AA33D021AeC8838 CHAIN
            // 0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8 WETH

            chainlinkFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(_chainlinkFeedAddress); 
            currency = IERC20(_currency); 

            for (uint256 i = 0; i < _whitelistedAddresses.length; i++) {
                whitelisted[_whitelistedAddresses[i]] = true;
            }

            for (uint256 i = 0; i < _maxPrincipleAmounts.length; i++) {
                maxPrinciple[_whitelistedAddresses[i]] = _maxPrincipleAmounts[i];
            }

            for (uint256 i = 0; i < _maxLoanDurations.length; i++) {
                maxLoanDurations.push(_maxLoanDurations[i]);
            }

            for (uint256 i = 0; i < _interestRates.length; i++) {
                interestRates.push(_interestRates[i]);
            }
            
            paused = false;

    }
```

For my `_whitelistedAddress` array, I have the following values:

```
["0x9a534628b4062e123ce7ee2222ec20b86e16ca8f","0x8a90cab2b38dba80c64b7734e58ee1db38b8992e","0x60e4d786628fea6478f785a6d7e704777c86a7c6","0xe785e82358879f061bc3dcac6f0444462d4b5330","0x49cf6f5d44e70224e2e23fdcdd2c053f30ada28b","0xc1caf0c19a8ac28c41fe59ba6c754e4b9bd54de9","0x1a92f7381b9f03921564a437210bb9396471050c","0xba30e5f9bb24caa003e9f2f0497ad287fdf95623","0xed5af388653567af2f388e6224dc7c4b3241c544","0xd78b76fcc33cd416da9d3d42f72649a23d7ac647"]
```

For my `maxPrincipleAmounts`, I have:

```
[1500,1200,6000,6000,5000,6000,2000,5000,4000,2000,2000]
```

Here are my global variables:

```
mapping(address => uint256) public maxPrinciple;
mapping(address => bool) public whitelisted;
uint256[] public interestRates;
uint256[] public maxLoanDurations;
bool public paused;
AggregatorV3Interface internal chainlinkFeed;
IERC20 public currency;
```

Any idea why this is failing in remix? I'm assuming it's because of gas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I count correctly your `_whitelistedAddress` has 10 elements and `maxPrincipleAmounts` has 11, but in your code you use `maxPrincipleAmounts.length` to iterate `_whitelistedAddresses`.

```js
for (uint256 i = 0; i < _maxPrincipleAmounts.length; i++) {
  maxPrinciple[_whitelistedAddresses[i]] = _maxPrincipleAmounts[i];
}
```

Therefore you access an invalid array index.

I would recommend a `require` to check that both arrays have the same length.